# Vim Opening File E325 Attention Error

Tags: vim, git-bash

On Git bash windows, I was editing .bash_profile file and then I decided not to save and closed the bash console. Now when I try to open the .bash_profile using vim, I get E325: Attention error. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By closing the console without exiting Vim first, the Vim process got killed, and Vim didn't have a chance to properly shut down. Vim uses *swap files* to store the last unpersisted changes to a buffer to avoid data loss in case of a crash; you can read the whole story at `:help E325`.

In your case, as you've consciously closed the console, there probably weren't any pending changes to your `.bash_profile` [worth saving]. (But there's still the swap file!) Therefore, when prompted

> ```
>   Swap file ".bash_profile.swp" already exists!
>   [O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort, (D)elete it:
> ```

answer with <kbd>D</kbd> to remove the outdated swap file. Alternatively, you can also search for the `.bash_profile.swp` (by default, it resides in the same directory as the edited file, likely `$HOME` in your case) and delete it manually. (It's hidden; use `ls -a` in Bash, or Windows Explorer.)

In the future, please exit Vim (`:qall[!]`) before closing the console it runs in, to allow for a clean shutdown.